# In gridstack.js, dragging feature isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apex, gridstack

I was using GridStack.JS in the codebelow (Basic Structure)

```
<div class="grid grid-stack">
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item cards grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="inner-grid">
    </div>
</div>
```

The script is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var options = {
            cellHeight: 80,
            verticalMargin: 10,
            columns: 14,
            acceptWidgets: '.',    
            animate: true,
            handle: '.draghandle',
            float: true,
            draggable: {handle: '.-content', scroll: true, appendTo:    'body'},

        };
        $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
    });
```

I have 2 issues here
 1. I cant get the grid-stack-items to be able to be dragged. Can someone help me?
 2. Secondly I am not able to scale the grid-stack-item container to increase its height to match the content

Any help will be appreciated greatly
I can also provide more clarity if needed on anything

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) You are specifying a drag handle `.-content` which does not exist in your markup!

2) Gridstack items obviously have a fixed width and height because they are a matrix, If you want an item to have more height you will have to specify it explicitly via `data-gs-height="x"`